# Angular 7: Got 405 Error When Detect Location

Tags: angular, typescript

I've problem error 405 (Method Not Allowed) when detect location.

**Service**

```
  public fetchWeatherDataByCoordinates(coordinates: ICoordinates): void {
    console.log("problem here")
    this.selectedLocationId.next(this.currentCoordinatesLocationId);
    if (coordinates) {
      const config = {
        url: this.getWeatherApiUrlByCoordinates(coordinates),
        byCoordinates: true
      };

      this.getWeatherDataByUrl(config);
    }
  }
```

this code add same file service

```
 private getWeatherApiUrlByCoordinates(coordinates: ICoordinates): string {
    const { lat, lon } = coordinates;
    const { weatherUrl } = environment;
    const { appid } = constants;
    return `${weatherUrl}?lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&appid=${appid}`;
  }
```

> edit add `getWeatherDataByUrl`

```
private getWeatherDataByUrl(config: any): void {
    this.transportService.get(config)
    .pipe(
      filter((res: HttpResponse<any>) => !!res.body),
      map((res: HttpResponse<any>) => <IWeatherData> res.body)
    )
    .subscribe((weatherData: IWeatherData) => {
      if (config.byCoordinates) {
        if (this.currentCoordinatesLocationId === -1) {
          this.selectedLocationId.next(weatherData.id);
        }
        this.currentCoordinatesLocationId = weatherData.id;
      }
      this.patchCurrentWeatherData(weatherData);
    });
  }
```

**Transport.service**

```
 public get(config: any): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const request: HttpRequest<any> = new HttpRequest<any>('GET', config.url, config.body);
    return this.http.request(request);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippets you posted I can't see which HTTP method you are using, but that `HTTP 405` you are seeing means that you are sending an HTTP request with a method (`GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, ...) that the server was not expecting.

For example, you get that if you issue a `GET` request against an endpoint that expects to receive a `POST`.

Check that method `getWeatherDataByUrl`, it seems there is where the call to `HttpClient` is.

Comment: Look at that method `transportService.get`, that is where the actual `HttpClient` invocation should be happening. It's possible there is a `transportService.post` you can invoke instead (or you'll need to create it). It could also be `put` instead of `post`. To know which one it should be, check the documentation of that API you are trying to access (the one you put in `weatherUrl`).

Comment: I've add `transportService` in my question

Comment: You can see it there, that method does a `'GET'`

Comment: Yup true.., I've change to method `POST` but I got same error too